# Permission on Profile on different section between 2 orgs

Tags: deployment, metadata

**Issue**
Assume 2 different orgs: Org A and Org B. Trying to move the metadata from Org A to Org B but having some hickups. Mainly on the profile level where we have the following:

- Org A: permission "Create and Customize Reports" is under section Administrative Permissions

  - Org B: permission "Create and Customize Reports" is under section General User Permissions

*However, when checking using the metadata. You can see that Org A has this permission using a retrieval. But, using a retrieval and having the permission manually set on Org B, the permission is not appearing in the metadata*. Why is this happening?

**Question 1**
Why are they are on a different section?

**Question 2**
Why is this giving an error when trying to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, but some permissions were not being migrated from an org to another. I noticed that the origin org was a sandbox in the Summer 15 release (API 34.0), while the destination org was a developer one in the previous release (API 33.0). Salesforce sometimes has different permissions/features/options/whatever that are added or removed in certain releases.

What happened was that I tried to migrate profiles from an org 34 to a 33, that didn't have the new permissions introduced in 34. And apparently the Salesforce Migration Tool is too dumb to notice that the permission doesn't exist and ignore it.

Also, in different releases, some system options might change places.

What I had to do to make my deployment work: create a Python script to "clear" the profile so it could be deployed to the org running the version 33.

Comment: Hi Renato, correct. But in this case, both environments were on the same release and the same API version is used. And indeed, I've used a similar approach to "clearing" the permissions of the profile which was causing the issue. Followed by performing a manual step for the permissions. What worries me is that, for the same API on 2 different orgs, certain permissions don't exist. Thanks for you reply!

Comment: Then, maybe it's a matter of different licenses? (one is a Professional Edition and the other a Enterprise Edition, or maybe a Developer Edition) That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Both the same version. Same licenses. We have a case open at Salesforce as well for the moment. Developer team there is looking into it. Thanks for your input!